# SQLite query 3 tables

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables (**A and B**) and the other one(**C**) is a mapping table between those 2 tables.

I want to select all columns **from A and B where A.id is mapped with any of the B.id.**

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B WHERE A.id = C.A_id AND B.id = C.B_id
```

Comment: [mcve] rule applies SQL question too. Share table structures you have and what you've tried so far. You can prepare http://sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: @lad2025 - I've updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is so unclear, but let's try.

From what you've posted I assume you want to join `table_A - joining_table_c - table_b` (**many-to-many relationship**):

```
CREATE TABLE #A(ID INT, name VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE #B(ID INT, col VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE #C(ID_a INT, ID_b INT);

INSERT INTO #A VALUES (1, 'aa'), (2,'bbb'), (3, 'ccc');
INSERT INTO #B VALUES (10, 'xxxx'), (11,'yyy'), (12, 'zzz');
INSERT INTO #C VALUES (1,10), (1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 10);

SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM #A a
JOIN #C c
  ON a.ID = c.ID_a
JOIN #B b
  ON b.ID = c.ID_b;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393788)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much, that select query is the key. I'm not so used with SQL queries, but you saved me. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandruCircus Great to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select table1.*,table2.*,table3.*
form table1
inner join table2
on table2.table1_id=table1.id
inner join table3
on table3.table1_id=table1.id
```

Comment: And where is table3 (C)?

Comment: Actually, table `C` from the question is **a mapping table** between A and B. I'm afraid you didn't understand the question.